# how to make a count on angular material's chips?

Tags: angular-material

this is about angular material's chips,
you know that, not allowed same name on it,
so i want to make a count how many times I write same name on it.
for example:
Apple (1), Papaya (1), Pome (1).
after that I write "Pome"  again and it'll become like this,
Apple (1), Papaya (1), Pome (2).

thank for your help...

Comment: Please post your code and explain what you are having trouble with.

Comment: oh, i am sory i am new here, wait a minutes..

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdSidenav', function($scope, $mdSidenav)
{
  $scope.names = [];
  $scope.isReadonly = false;
}]);
```

```css
body{
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="StarterApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  Tags :
  <md-chips ng-model="names" readonly="isReadonly"></md-chips>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isReadonly">Enabled</input>
</div>
```

just wanna adding some feature to the chips to count ho many times i write the same words on it